# Do not add a specific unnumbered \chapter* to the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I am working on a document that makes use of a document class file which forces all unnumbered chapters created with `\chapter*` to appear in the table of contents.

The problem is that I need to add an unnumbered chapter to the document which (exceptionally) I don't want it to appear in the TOC. But I can't because very time `\chapter*` is used it is added to the TOC via the `\addcontentsline` macro.

Here is the fragment of the `.cls` file that instructs every `\chapter*` to appear in the TOC:

```
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
  \noindent
  \begin{center}
    \LARGE\sffamily\bfseries \MakeUppercase{#1} \par\nobreak
  \end{center}
  \vspace{3ex}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\large\sffamily\bfseries #1}  % <-- PUTS EVERY CHAPTER* IN THE TOC!
}
```

How can I circunvent this without affecting other chapters on the document that are defined with `\chapter*`?

Is it possible to define a custom chapter command that does everything `\chapter*` does except adding an entry in the TOC?

Comment: Simply type your headline and format it as specified in the definition. There is no need to put all in a newcommand.

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein I didn't realize that the definition in the `.cls` file is simply defining the formatting for the chapter headline until I read your comment. So I used the same formatting for the headline of my unlisted chapter and job done! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can temporarily deactivate the `\addcontentsline` macro to just capture its arguments but do nothing with them. Something like

```
\begingroup
\renewcomand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}% Make \addcontentsline a no-op
\chapter*{Very special starred chapter}
\endgroup
```

The grouping provides a scope within which macro changes is considered temporary (unless changes are made explicitly global).

Comment: +1.  And if you're using hyperref, you'll need to change the 3 to 5 (or 4?).